# Programmatically "Edit Policies" of packaged Connected App in Subscriber org

Tags: managed-package, metadata-api, connected-apps, isv

My managed package contains a `Connected App`. Until now subscriber admins needed to perform many error-prone configuration steps after installation in `Setup > Manage Connected apps > connected app selection > Edit policies`. For example:

1. Change Start-, ASC- and Issuer URLs
2. Edit the IDP-Certificate

My goal now is to add a nice Setup screen to my app where most of those steps are automatically done using Apex code and the use of the Metadata API.

Can anybody please provide example code on how to do that?